# Permission denied error when trying to install with wubi

Tags: installation, windows, permissions, wubi

I run into problem when tried to install Ubuntu 11.04 on Windows 7 using wubi installer .
It downloads the image for sometime and ends up with the error that says

Permission denied: for more details see the log file

In the log it seems to be like 
DownloadError: Problem connecting to tracker - urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')

but my network is good and I checked it.

Tried using wubi several times, but ends up with same problem.

Log content:

```
10-08 16:56 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished get_metalink
10-08 16:56 DEBUG  TaskList: New task download
10-08 16:56 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Running download...
10-08 16:56 DEBUG  btdownloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/11.04/ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent > C:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso
10-08 18:02 ERROR  TaskList: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 229, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 221, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\bittorrent\Rerequester.py", line 96, in fail
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Problem connecting to tracker - urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 79, in download
  File "\lib\bittorrent\download.py", line 303, in download
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 256, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 229, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 221, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\bittorrent\Rerequester.py", line 96, in fail
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Problem connecting to tracker - urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')


10-08 18:02 ERROR  TaskList: Non fatal error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 229, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 221, in listen_forever
  File "\lib\bittorrent\Rerequester.py", line 96, in fail
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 70, in error_callback
DownloadError: Problem connecting to tracker - urlopen error (10060, 'Operation timed out')

 in task download
10-08 18:02 DEBUG  TaskList: ### Finished download
10-08 18:02 ERROR  TaskList: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 492, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 347, in download_iso
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
10-08 18:02 DEBUG  TaskList: # Cancelling tasklist
10-08 18:02 DEBUG  TaskList: # Finished tasklist
10-08 18:02 ERROR  root: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 57, in run
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 131, in select_task
  File "\lib\wubi\application.py", line 157, in run_installer
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\tasklist.py", line 197, in __call__
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 492, in get_iso
  File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\backend.py", line 347, in download_iso
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: u'C:\\ubuntu\\install\\ubuntu-11.04-desktop-amd64.iso'
```

Answer (score 4):

Wubi is trying to download the desktop CD ISO for the install using a bittorrent client. It requires that pyrun.exe (the python runtime that Wubi uses) be given permission to your windows firewall. If you granted pyrun.exe firewall access (there would have been a popup asking permission) then you may be blocked by an upstream firewall e.g. some colleges/universities block bittorrents.

If that's the case you should download the desktop CD iso yourself from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download and save it in the same directory as wubi.exe before running (and Wubi will find it and use it).

Answer (score 1):

It worked for my by downloading the image and placing it in the same folder where the wubi.exe sits in. And one should not forget to disable network before executing this. It works smooth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which one will work, lets try several solution:

```
1. run wubi.exe with right click [rus as administrator]
2. Try to install ubuntu on another drive [if run as admin does not work][expect C]
3. If you will get any disk error during wubi installation then just click continue several times. Surprisingly it works.
```

Answer (score 0):

Old Wubi versions have bugs but i have found a solution from a forum post at ubuntuforums.org i can't find the same post but i have the links to patched files. This files are working. I tried the wubi from this link and worked.

Thanks to hakuna_matata

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/6uqomp8l1frcd1y/AAAhSCimTaYE-94egbmc1X_na?dl=0