# Unable to install ubuntu12.04 using WUBI

Tags: 12.04, wubi

I am trying to install ubuntu12.04LTS.

Not being able to install ubuntu using wubi. after running wubi and selecting the drive and passwords etc. , the download starts but following error is displayed:

```
An error occured:

IOError: <urlopenerror (7,'getaddrinfo failed')>
For more information please see the logfile
  c:\docume~1\owner\locals~1\temp\wubi-12.04.3-rev279.log
```

How to solve this error?Please help me on this.

I can't able to post full contents of log file.

Contents of `Log File` is below:

```
10-11 22:00 INFO   root: === wubi 12.04.3 rev279 ===
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  root: Logfile is c:\docume~1\owner\locals~1\temp\wubi-12.04.3-rev279.log
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  root: sys.argv = ['main.pyo', '--exefile="C:\\Documents and Settings\\owner\\Desktop\\wubi.exe"']
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: data_dir=C:\DOCUME~1\owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl8E.tmp\data
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: 7z=C:\DOCUME~1\owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl8E.tmp\bin\7z.exe
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: startup_folder=C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Fetching basic info...
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: original_exe=C:\Documents and Settings\owner\Desktop\wubi.exe
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: platform=win32
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: osname=nt
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: language=en_US
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: encoding=cp1252
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: arch=amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend: Parsing isolist=C:\DOCUME~1\owner\LOCALS~1\Temp\pyl8E.tmp\data\isolist.ini
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Xubuntu-i386
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-i386
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Xubuntu-amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-i386
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Edubuntu-amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-i386
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Ubuntu-i386
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Mythbuntu-amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Kubuntu-i386
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  CommonBackend:   Adding distro Lubuntu-amd64
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: Fetching host info...
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: registry_key=Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Wubi
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows version=xp
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_version2=Microsoft Windows XP
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_sp=Service Pack 3
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_build=2600
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: gmt=5
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: country=US
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: timezone=America/New_York
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_username=owner
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_full_name=owner
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: user_directory=C:\Documents and Settings\owner
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language_code=1033
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: windows_language=English
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: processor_name=Intel(R) Pentium(R) Dual  CPU  E2140  @ 1.60GHz 
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: bootloader=xp
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: system_drive=Drive(C: hd 6105.2265625 mb free ntfs)
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(C: hd 6105.2265625 mb free ntfs)
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(D: hd 38637.5 mb free fat32)
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(E: hd 8747.6875 mb free fat32)
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(F: hd 24030.09375 mb free fat32)
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(G: cd 0.0 mb free )
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(H: cd 0.0 mb free cdfs)
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: drive=Drive(I: removable 0.0 mb free )
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: uninstaller_path=None
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_target_dir=None
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: previous_distro_name=None
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_id=67699721
10-11 22:00 DEBUG  WindowsBackend: keyboard_layout=us
```

Full Log File can be viewed at http://pastebin.com/18SZHpZ0

Comment: Did you check to see what the error log states? Check the log in: c:\docume~1\owner\locals~1\temp\wubi-12.04.3-rev279.log

Comment: @Atari911: I saw error log states.But i can't understand how to solve this error.

Comment: Add the contents of the log file to your post so others can get a look at it... Without the log there is little we can do to understand the problem.

Comment: @Atari: I have add contents of log file.

Comment: What version windows? Does the computer have uefi?

Comment: @Mateo : Version of window is XP. My computer have not UEFI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following are the relevant lines of your log file that indicate what the problem is:

> 12-17 09:40 DEBUG  btdownloader: downloading http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04.3/ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso.torrent > D:\ubuntu\install\ubuntu-12.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso
>
> 12-17 10:45 ERROR  TaskList: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 229, in listen_forever
> >
> > File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 69, in error_callback
>
> DownloadError: Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> > File "\lib\bittorrent\RawServer.py", line 221, in listen_forever
> >
> > File "\lib\bittorrent\Rerequester.py", line 96, in fail
> >
> > File "\lib\wubi\backends\common\btdownloader.py", line 69, in error_callback
>
> DownloadError: Problem connecting to tracker - urlopen error (7, 'getaddrinfo failed')>

Wubi is trying to download the ISO image of Ubuntu as a torrent using btdowloader, but btdownloader is unable to connect to the torrent's tracker. There are a number of reasons this may happen:

- Your client can't get through your firewall.
- Your ISP's DNS server is down.
- Your ISP's DNS server can't resolve the tracker's domain to an IP address.
- The Tracker is down and isn't responding.

If you are using the Windows firewall (or another software based firewall on your computer), then give pyrun.exe (the python runtime that Wubi uses) permission to your windows firewall. If that does not work, then you should download the desktop CD iso yourself from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download and save it in the same directory as wubi.exe before running (and Wubi will find it and use it).

Information in this answer taken from:

- http://torrentfreaknews.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/error-messages-guide-for-torrent-clients.html
- [Permission denied error when trying to install with wubi](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64813/permission-denied-error-when-trying-to-install-with-wubi)

Comment: I need require assistance so I have add log file in my question.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be the full log file. Please upload the full log file somewhere (e.g. pastebin) and post a link to it. Without being able to see the full log file, it is impossible to know exactly what happened.

Comment: I have created Full log file in pastebin. Link of Log file is " http://pastebin.com/18SZHpZ0 ".

Comment: Your answer is working for me. My computer internet speed was slow.

Comment: @Jaiminpandya please accept my answer if it worked for you. That would be much appreciated.